# Allow opening of local files in HTML5 Phonegapped Android app

Tags: android, cordova

I have a HTML5 app. Which runs fine in a browser. And fine when wrapped up as an iOS app.
However when I build for Android I am getting the following message when debugging through adb.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/www/data/translations.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1
```

This occurs when I call try to load the file with `$.getJSON`

Apparently this can be resolved in JAVA with

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

However, I need a way to do this in a HTML5 app wrapped up with phonegap. How can I turn this setting on?

Comment: It would appear sticking in the latest cordova jar resolves the issue. So going to close this.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the lastest (at time of posting 2.8.1) cordova jar resolved the issue.