# Open pdf in .apk with native android application using phonegap

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I am coding a app for iOS and Android using Phonegap (version: 2.7.0). The pdf file is file:///android_asset/www/test.pdf (compressed in the .apk).

I try to open this pdf with a native pdf viewer like:

```
window.open('file:///android_asset/www/test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

The command above works on browsers and iOS (you have to use `_blank` instead of `_system`)

I tried to load the file with the Phonegap File API to the sdcard, but I read its not possible to access files in the android_asset/www.

Is it possible to open the pdf directly from the android_asset/www path?
Is it possible to copy the file to sdcard end open it from there?
Maybe its possible with android install scripts?

Edit:

I added this to my .java file in the /src/com/...etc .java File:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {        
  super.appView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

But there is still the same problem...

I have output from `adb -d logcat` it happens when i start the app and click the pdf link:

`I/ActivityManager(22040): Displayed com.company.appname/.Appname: +1s611ms
I/ActivityManager(22040): Displayed com.tf.thinkdroid.samsung/com.tf.thinkdroid.pdf.app.PdfRenderScreen: +1s549ms
D/CordovaLog(27549): exception firing pause event from native
I/Web Console(27549): exception firing pause event from native at undefined:1
...
I/InputReader(22040): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
I/InputDispatcher(22040): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40a9f450 com.tf.thinkdroid.samsung/com.tf.thinkdroid.pdf.app.PdfRenderScreen (server)'
I/InputReader(22040): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
I/InputDispatcher(22040): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40a9f450 com.tf.thinkdroid.samsung/com.tf.thinkdroid.pdf.app.PdfRenderScreen (server)'
....
D/DroidGap(27549): Resuming the App`

Comment: please read this answer that will help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462707/if-link-is-http-google-com-it-worked-but-if-i-change-link-to-my-pdf-url-i/38463242#38463242

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work in your case:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Originally answered here: [Allow opening of local files in HTML5 Phonegapped Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188794/allow-opening-of-local-files-in-html5-phonegapped-android-app)

Comment: Thanks for this, but i guess for the extern application its still not allowed to access files from my app...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP and many unsuccessful approaches later I came to the following solution (tested with Cordova 3.1.0 & Samsung Galaxy S3):

### Solution

First, get the file by [requesting the file system](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) and then download it from your server with [fileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download). After completing the download call the FileOpener (which will open a pop up where to choose from apps like Adobe Reader). Note: Make sure to include the FileTransfer feature via CLI/Terminal: **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file**

- Navigate to your project folder
- Open CLI/Terminal and type in: **`cordova plugin add https://github.com/don/FileOpener.git`**
- After successful download and storage of your file on the device (see above) you open it with: **`window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.example.application/document.doc")`**

That's it! Good luck!