# Cross-origin Resource Sharing in Android via Ionic and Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cors

My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188794/allow-opening-of-local-files-in-html5-phonegapped-android-app#_=_) question.

I have an HTML5-based Android app. It is wrapped in Cordova, and built using the Ionic Framework. When launched, the app loads an index.html file, which is located locally on the device and makes a cross-origin resource request. It therefore does not load for Android API 18 and higher.

The workaround to this restriction is to enable the `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` setting. Given that my project is built using the Ionic Framework, what would be the correct way to enable this flag? Would I necessarily need to go into the Android project to enable the flag, or is there a cleaner way to do it via a settings file?

I have inherited this project and have very little experience with Ionic, Cordova, and HTML5, therefore any detail would be greatly appreciated. In the question above, the solution was to update to Cordova 2.8.1. I am running Cordova 5.1.1. and still experience the problem.

Comment: which emulator are you using? its on real device or on ripple emulator in cordova

Comment: I'm using the standard android emulator and also testing on device. In both cases the index.html file does not load unless running an older version of android.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a origin problem try to whitelist your remote domain.
Read this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html